# Better character movement according to touch location

Tags: objective-c, ios8, sprite-kit

I have a character spawned in the middle of a 3 by 3 platform (orthogonal & 2D sprite game). The platform is made up of 9 tiles. The character needs to move up if the touch is above him, left if touch is left of him and so forth. He only moves up, down, left & right; not diagonally. I have all of this working BUT it's clunky - as in the character doesn't always "listen" & ends up going in another direction closest to the touch. Can someone please take a look & tell me what to do to fix the code? It seems the real problem with the code below is when a player touches the screen somewhere within one of the four 90 degree angles & the system doesn't exactly know what to do...or something like that.

```
//This movement method is called by 'touchesBegan' method inside an SKScene (Good ol' GameScene).
-(void)moveCharRedTo:(CGPoint)touchedLocation
{
    //If touch is to the left of the character then move character to the left by 1 tile.
    if (touchedLocation.x < _playerChar.position.x)
    {
        _charRedPointPos = [_platformLayer coordForPoint:_playerChar.position];
        _charRedRight = CGPointMake(_charRedPointPos.x - 1, _charRedPointPos.y);

        if ([_platformLayer isValidTileCoord:_charRedRight] && ![self tileAtCoord:_charRedRight hasAnyProps:(noGoCategory)])
        {
            _charRedRight = [_platformLayer pointForCoord:_charRedRight];
            [_playerChar runAction:[SKAction moveTo:_charRedRight duration:0.0]];
        }
    }
    //Move right.
    if (touchedLocation.x > _playerChar.position.x)
    {
        _charRedPointPos = [_platformLayer coordForPoint:_playerChar.position];
        _charRedRight = CGPointMake(_charRedPointPos.x + 1, _charRedPointPos.y);

        if ([_platformLayer isValidTileCoord:_charRedRight] && ![self tileAtCoord:_charRedRight hasAnyProps:(blueTileCategory)])
        {
            _charRedRight = [_platformLayer pointForCoord:_charRedRight];
            [_playerChar runAction:[SKAction moveTo:_charRedRight duration:0.0]];
        }
    }

    //Move down.
    if (touchedLocation.y < _playerChar.position.y)
    {
        _charRedPointPos = [_platformLayer coordForPoint:_playerChar.position];
        _charRedDown = CGPointMake(_charRedPointPos.x, _charRedPointPos.y + 1);

        if ([_platformLayer isValidTileCoord:_charRedDown] && ![self tileAtCoord:_charRedDown hasAnyProps:(noGoCategory)])
        {
            _charRedDown = [_platformLayer pointForCoord:_charRedDown];
            [_playerChar runAction:[SKAction moveTo:_charRedDown duration:0.0]];
        }
    }
    //Move up.
    if (touchedLocation.y > _playerChar.position.y) //else
    {
        _charRedPointPos = [_platformLayer coordForPoint:_playerChar.position];
        _charRedUp = CGPointMake(_charRedPointPos.x, _charRedPointPos.y - 1);

        if ([_platformLayer isValidTileCoord:_charRedUp] && ![self tileAtCoord:_charRedUp hasAnyProps:(noGoCategory)])
        {
            _charRedUp = [_platformLayer pointForCoord:_charRedUp];
            [_playerChar runAction:[SKAction moveTo:_charRedUp duration:0.0]];
        }
        //NSLog(@"Was on (%f,%f)", _charRedPointPos.x, _charRedPointPos.y);
    }

    [_playerChar movementAnimation]; //Little animation method for every time the character moves.
}
```

Comment: I assume your character always moves to left first as long as the touch happened to the left(even if it was the touched position was 1 pixel to the left and 100 on top?)

Comment: Well sort of. Except for left & right it does that with up & down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you need to pick just 1 direction in which to move. Find out which way to move like below.

```
NS_ENUM(unsigned short, MovementDirection)
{
    Left = 0,
    Right = 1,
    Top = 2,
    Bottom = 3
}

-(MovementDirection)movementDirectionBetweenCurrentPoint:(CGPoint)currentPoint newPoint:(CGPoint)newPoint
{
    double dx = newPoint.x - currentPoint.x;
    double dy = newPoint.y - currentPoint.y;

    if(dx > dy)
        return (dx > 0) Right : Left;
    else
        return (dy > 0) Top : Bottom;
}
-(void)moveCharRedTo:(CGPoint)touchedLocation
{
    MovementDirection direction = [self movementDirectionBetweenCurrentPoint:_playerChar.position newPoint:touchedLocation];
    //If touch is to the left of the character then move character to the left by 1 tile.
    if (direction == Left)
    {
        _charRedPointPos = [_platformLayer coordForPoint:_playerChar.position];
        _charRedRight = CGPointMake(_charRedPointPos.x - 1, _charRedPointPos.y);

        if ([_platformLayer isValidTileCoord:_charRedRight] && ![self tileAtCoord:_charRedRight hasAnyProps:(noGoCategory)])
        {
            _charRedRight = [_platformLayer pointForCoord:_charRedRight];
            [_playerChar runAction:[SKAction moveTo:_charRedRight duration:0.0]];
        }
    }
    //Move right.
    else if (direction == Right)
    {
        _charRedPointPos = [_platformLayer coordForPoint:_playerChar.position];
        _charRedRight = CGPointMake(_charRedPointPos.x + 1, _charRedPointPos.y);

        if ([_platformLayer isValidTileCoord:_charRedRight] && ![self tileAtCoord:_charRedRight hasAnyProps:(blueTileCategory)])
        {
            _charRedRight = [_platformLayer pointForCoord:_charRedRight];
            [_playerChar runAction:[SKAction moveTo:_charRedRight duration:0.0]];
        }
    }

    //Move down.
    else if (direction == Bottom)
    {
        _charRedPointPos = [_platformLayer coordForPoint:_playerChar.position];
        _charRedDown = CGPointMake(_charRedPointPos.x, _charRedPointPos.y + 1);

        if ([_platformLayer isValidTileCoord:_charRedDown] && ![self tileAtCoord:_charRedDown hasAnyProps:(noGoCategory)])
        {
            _charRedDown = [_platformLayer pointForCoord:_charRedDown];
            [_playerChar runAction:[SKAction moveTo:_charRedDown duration:0.0]];
        }
    }
    //Move up.
    else if (direction == Top) //else
    {
        _charRedPointPos = [_platformLayer coordForPoint:_playerChar.position];
        _charRedUp = CGPointMake(_charRedPointPos.x, _charRedPointPos.y - 1);

        if ([_platformLayer isValidTileCoord:_charRedUp] && ![self tileAtCoord:_charRedUp hasAnyProps:(noGoCategory)])
        {
            _charRedUp = [_platformLayer pointForCoord:_charRedUp];
            [_playerChar runAction:[SKAction moveTo:_charRedUp duration:0.0]];
        }
        //NSLog(@"Was on (%f,%f)", _charRedPointPos.x, _charRedPointPos.y);
    }

    [_playerChar movementAnimation]; //Little animation method for every time the character moves.
}
```

Comment: Woop woop that's very nice! Thank you tons

Comment: By the way, I get an error inside the '-(enum MovementDirection)movementDirectionBetweenCurrentPoint:(CGPoint)currentPoint newPoint:(CGPoint)newPoint' method. Where the return values are located:
if(dx > dy)
    {
        return (dx > 0) Right : Left;
    }
    else
    {
        return (dy > 0) Top : Bottom;
    }
It says "Expected ']'" for the 2 statements where 'return' are located. I'm not sure what it wants.

Comment: Opa, I figured it out. It wants the '?' symbol between the comparison & right/left values: return (dx > 0) ? Right : Left;

Comment: @Krekin whoops. sorry about that. I didn't write that code on XCode :)